# How to change the syntax theme only for editor window, not entire UI

Tags: themes, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code

It seems I can only change a theme for the entire UI in vscode. How do I change the theme for just the syntax highlighting and leave the UI as is?

Answer (score 0):

Open issue: [Separate workbench theme and syntax theme #25986](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25986)